# How to plot a variable against itself based on factor levels?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a dataset of temperatures measured at various times in different cities:

```
location    time      temperature  
Guangzhou   evening   21
Tokyo       evening   39
Lima        morning   77
Shenzhen    morning   76
Lahore      noon      24
Shanghai    evening   80
Tianjin     evening   91
Delhi       morning   51
Dhaka       morning   6 
Karachi     noon      84
Sao Paulo   noon      49
Tianjin     noon      89
Beijing     evening   3 
Delhi       evening   93
Dhaka       evening   65
Istanbul    evening   37
Karachi     evening   81
Kinshasa    evening   89
Lahore      evening   2 
Lima        evening   77
Manila      evening   74
Moscow      evening   60
Mumbai      evening   41
Sao Paulo   evening   13
Seoul       evening   65
Shenzhen    evening   3 
Wuhan       evening   30
Beijing     morning   61
Guangzhou   morning   29
Karachi     morning   84
Kinshasa    morning   4 
Lahore      morning   12
Manila      morning   89
Moscow      morning   71
Mumbai      morning   7 
Sao Paulo   morning   87
Seoul       morning   74
Shanghai    morning   63
Tianjin     morning   32
Tokyo       morning   81
Wuhan       morning   21
Beijing     noon      38
Chengdu     noon      51
Delhi       noon      61
Dhaka       noon      55
Istanbul    noon      12
Kinshasa    noon      77
Lima        noon      86
Manila      noon      47
Moscow      noon      2 
Mumbai      noon      41
Seoul       noon      97
Shenzhen    noon      24
Tokyo       noon      94
```

I want to use ggplot and dplyr to make a scatter plot where:

- x axis is temperature measured in the morning
- y axis is temperature measured at noon
- each city is a point
- cities missing data for both noon and morning are excluded

How can I do this?

Comment: merge subsets of evening and morning by location. Then you'll have a dataframe with two columns for your scatterplot.

Comment: @42- That is of course the obvious solution, to rearrange it. But is there no way to do it without rearranging the data frame?

Answer (score 0):

The gather() function from tidyr package is what you need.

Let's suppose your data is storage on a object so called: data, then...

```
data %>% 
  tidyr::spread(key = time, value = temperature) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = morning, y = noon, label = location)) + 
  geom_jitter() + 
  geom_text(nudge_y = 4)
```

spread(): It convert your "wide" to “long” data format, for that we need to inform the "key", i.e., the variable whose values go to the columns and the "value", i.e., the variable has the information to fill the dataframe.

Hope it helps!

[image]